# Correctly using quote to call a variable based on a value

Tags: r

I am trying to understand how to use the `data$VARIABLE` argument when I set the `VARIABLE` as a global value.

Using the `iris` dataset I create two datasets. (`iris` and `iris2`).

```
data(iris)
iris2 <- iris[,1:4]^2
colnames(iris2) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
```

What I want to do is to `cbind` some specific columns together such as:

```
cbind(iris$Sepal.Length, iris2$col1, iris$Species)
```

However I want to define the `VARIABLE` outside the `cbind` function.

I am trying

```
var1 <- quote(Sepal.Length)
var2 <- quote(col1)
var3 <- quote(Species)

cbind(iris$var1, iris2$var2, iris$var3)
```

However this isn't working.

How can I assign the variable outside the `cbind` function?

Comment: This should work `cbind(iris[,as.character(var1)], iris[,as.character(var1)], iris[,as.character(var1)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is `quote` it is a `symbol`

```
str(var1)
#symbol Sepal.Length
```

we can `deparse/as.character` to convert it to `character` and use `[` instead of `$`

```
head(cbind(iris[deparse(var1)], iris2[deparse(var2)], iris[deparse(var3)]))
#  Sepal.Length  col1 Species
#1          5.1 26.01  setosa
#2          4.9 24.01  setosa
#3          4.7 22.09  setosa
#4          4.6 21.16  setosa
#5          5.0 25.00  setosa
#6          5.4 29.16  setosa
```

---

Or if we are using `quo`

```
library(dplyr)
var1 <- quo(Sepal.Length)
var2 <- quo(col1)
var3 <- quo(Species)
iris %>% 
     select(!!var1, !! var3) %>%
     # or use the curly-curly operator
     # select({{var1}}, {{var3}}) %>%
     bind_cols(iris2 %>% 
                  select(!! var2))
```

Comment: Thanks! anyway I can do this in a magrittr pipe?

Comment: Didn't know of the `deparse` function before!

Comment: @user8959427 f you are using `tidyverse`, then it can be different

Comment: I am using `tidyverse` functions. I have come across `quo`, `enquo` but not sure which works with my problem.

Comment: @user8959427 prefix `en` is used when it is within a function.  I updated with the dplyr optioin

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks! One final question what exactly does the `!!` part of the code do?

Comment: @user8959427 It is doing the evaluation i.e. it is specifying not to literally evaluate the 'var1' or check for var1 in the column names, but the value stored in that

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. New question is the `curly-curly operator` the same as the `!!`?

Comment: @user8959427 It is also used mostly within a function.  Does two things in one. i.e we don't need `enquo + !!` it does both to evaluate unquoted arguments to function

Answer (score 2):

`[[` and `setNames` will accepted symbols:

```
setNames(data.frame(iris[[var1]], iris2[[var2]], iris[[var3]]), c(var1, var2, var3))
```

giving:

```
  Sepal.Length  col1 Species
1          5.1 26.01  setosa
2          4.9 24.01  setosa
3          4.7 22.09  setosa
4          4.6 21.16  setosa
5          5.0 25.00  setosa
6          5.4 29.16  setosa
...etc...
```